# Unable to generate ssh public key when installing Redmine

Tags: debian, ssh, redmine

I am trying to set up a Redmine on my server, and I am following [THIS](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_2_integrated_with_Gitolite_2_on_Debian_Wheezy_with_Apache_and_Phusion_Passenger) setup guide. I have used this guide before on my VPS and it worked perfectly however on this server I get following error when I try to generate public key.

```
aristotle:~# sudo su - redmine
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
redmine@aristotle:/$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/gitolite_admin_id_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
open //.ssh/gitolite_admin_id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: //.ssh/gitolite_admin_id_rsa.
redmine@aristotle:/$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved ... I just had to do

`sudo mkdir .ssh` in that directory

Comment: Why exactly you needed to do that?

Comment: to generate key for admin user

Comment: Could you give us the pointers that lead you to your answer, is what I wanted to ask.

Comment: It said "no such file or directory" i was confused at first.. as i have simply forgot that .ssh is a file, and since that error was thrown this file did not exist so i just create it